# Git bash curl request - URL using bad / illegal format or missing url

Tags: curl, git-bash

[image]

Any ideas why im getting this error - ive tried moving the URL to the end, wrapped in single and double quotes

```
AUTH_TOKEN = $(curl -X POST\
 https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/tokens\
  -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=10'\
  -H "Accept: application/json"\
  -H "Content-Type: application/json"\
  -k "C:\curl\cacert.pem"\
  -d "{"auth": {"RAX-KSKEY:apiKeyCredentials": {"username": "fakeuser","apiKey": "fakeapikey"}}}")

echo "$AUTH_TOKEN"
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to escape the `"`

```
-d "{\"auth\": {\"RAX-KSKEY
```